# c socket programming, only receiving one line at a time

Tags: c, sockets

I am having a problem of only receiving one line at a time in my client side. I am trying ti figure a way to receive the whole stream at once. Can anyone correct what I have in regards to the receiving issue? I have included the client code and a portion of the server side code I believe to be relavent.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    FILE *log;
    int opt;
    int count = 0;
    int sock, bytes_received;
    char send_data[2048],recv_data[2048];
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    if(remove("client_log")) ;

    if(argc == 2)
    {
      if(strcmp(argv[1], "-v") == 0)
      {
        log = fopen("client_log", "a");
        opt = 1;
      }
      else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-V") == 0)
      {
        log = fopen("client_log", "a");
        opt = 2;
      }
    }

    }
    else
      opt = 0;

    host = gethostbyname("127.0.0.0");

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(noneya);
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
                sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Connect");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {

      bytes_received=recv(sock,recv_data,2048,0);
      recv_data[bytes_received] = '\0';

      if (strcmp(recv_data , "q") == 0 || strcmp(recv_data , "Q") == 0)
      {
       close(sock);
       break;
      }

       else
      {
        if(opt != 0)
          fprintf(log, "\n Received Data: %s \n", recv_data);
        if(opt == 2)
          printf("\nReceived Data: %s \n" , recv_data);
      }

       if(count == 0)
       {
         printf("Pick an option: \n");
         printf("1 - to search by Department only\n");
         printf("2 - to search by Department and Class Number\n");
         printf("3 - to search more specifically\n");
         printf("q or Q - to Quit");
       }
       printf("\nSEND: ");
       gets(send_data);
       if(count == 0)
       {
         count = (int)send_data;
         if(count == 3)
            count++;
       }
       else if(count > 0)
         count--;

        if(opt != 0)
          fprintf(log, "\n Sending Data: %s \n", send_data);
        if(opt == 2)
          printf("\n Sending Data: %s \n" , send_data);

      if (strcmp(send_data , "q") != 0 && strcmp(send_data , "Q") != 0)
       send(sock,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);

       else
      {
       send(sock,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);
       close(sock);
       break;
      }

    }
return 0;
}
```

Here is the client side of things:

```
 case 1:

            fread(data, sizeof(sched_record), MAX_RECORD, filePointer);
            fclose(filePointer);
            char send_data[] = "Enter Department Name";
            send(connected, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0);
            bytes_received = recv(connected, recv_data, BUF, 0);
            recv_data[bytes_received] = '\0';
            strcpy(tempDept, recv_data);
            for (i=0; i<MAX_RECORD; i++){
                if ((strcmp(tempDept, data[i].Dept)==0) && tempCourse != data[i].course){
                        sprintf(send_data,"%s %d", data[i].Dept, data[i].course);
                        send(connected, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0);
                        tempCourse = data[i].course;

                }
            }
        break;
```

I can provide more info if needed. I believe the server side is ok. I have compiled with -Wall and -Wextra and received no warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving data a line at a time because it's being sent a line at a time. The fact that it ends up coming out this way is pure luck, though; TCP streams can be split up and recombined arbitrarily by the client TCP stack, or by buffering on the other end. You need some form of explicit framing in the stream -- for instance, a count sent before each line, or a `\n` at the end of a line.

Comment: when you are saying "end of a line" are you suggesting a \n in the sprintf statements? I am not following what you are saying, can you show me?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Otherwise you may receive all the data you sent mashed together like this: `"Department 123Department 456Department 789"`

Comment: That did not seem to work. I still have to depress enter to get the next line of information.

Answer (score 1):

To add on duskwuff's answer, what you have encountered here is the need to use a *stream based protocol*.

Because TCP is not message oriented (unlike UDP, and other more exotic message protocols), you are sending and receiving a single stream of bytes. Basically, if you were to consider your client as the writer of a book, and your server as its reader, then in the world of TCP all punctuation is removed :).

As the programmer, it is your job to provide a well defined way to be able to encode and/or embed where one message/frame ends and the next begins. Using newlines is the simplest method, but any TCP based based protocol either uses lengths, or delimiters, or a combination thereof (see HTTP).

Comment: Forgive me here, but not seeing how what you said helps me? Perhaps an example might help?